How to add a non-moving button in reality view?
I want to place the button in the immersive view but the problem is that it is sticking to the anchor but not following the user.
I want it to be placed like this, the arrow ones:

I tried to use the Attachments API to place the buttons but it is staying on the defined place but not moving along with the user.
//
//  ImmersiveView.swift
//  StudioTest
//
//  Created by Lahfir on 15/11/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import UIKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel
    @EnvironmentObject var movementModel: VerticalMovementModel
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ImmersiveViewModel()
    @State private var attachmentsProvider = AttachmentsProvider()
    @State private var targetEntity: Entity?
    @State private var subscriptions = [EventSubscription]()
    @State private var initialScale: Float = 1.0
    @State private var currentPosition: SIMD3<Float>?
    @State private var isManipulating: Bool = false
    @State private var positionUpdateTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    @State private var audioController: AudioPlaybackController?
    
    @State private var userAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    static let buttonQuery = EntityQuery(where: .has(SampleButtonComponent.self))
    static let runtimeQuery = EntityQuery(where: .has(SampleButtonRuntimeComponent.self))
    
    private var titleFont: Font {
        .system(size: 48, weight: .semibold)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let currentScene = appModel.currentScene {
            RealityView { content, attachments in
                do {
                    let sceneEntity = try await SceneLoader.shared.loadScene(currentScene.rcScene)
                    
                    movementModel.updateLimits(for: currentScene.rcScene)
                    print(" Scene loaded: \(currentScene.rcScene.fileName)")
                    print(" Vertical limits set - Ascend: \(movementModel.ascendLimit), Descend: \(movementModel.descendLimit)")

                    subscriptions.append(
                        content.subscribe(
                            to: ComponentEvents.DidAdd.self,
                            componentType: SampleButtonComponent.self
                        ) { event in
                            createButtonView(for: event.entity)
                        }
                    )

                    let initialTransform = Transform(
                        scale: sceneEntity.transform.scale,
                        rotation: sceneEntity.transform.rotation,
                        translation: .zero
                    )
                    sceneEntity.transform = initialTransform
                    content.add(sceneEntity)
                    targetEntity = sceneEntity

                    content.add(userAnchor)

                    if let controlsAttachment = attachments.entity(for: "movement_controls") {
                        controlsAttachment.position = [0, -0.1, -0.5]
                        controlsAttachment.components.set(BillboardComponent())
                        userAnchor.addChild(controlsAttachment)
                    }

                    print(" Adding control buttons to immersive view")
                    let audioEntity = Entity()
                    content.add(audioEntity)
                    
                    Task {
                        await loadAndPlayWelcomeAudio(for: audioEntity)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("❌ Failed to load scene: \(error)")
                }
            } update: { content, attachments in
                content.entities.first?.scene?.performQuery(Self.runtimeQuery).forEach { entity in
                    guard let component = entity.components[SampleButtonRuntimeComponent.self],
                          let attachmentEntity = attachments.entity(for: component.attachmentTag)
                    else { return }
                    
                    guard attachmentEntity.parent == nil else { return }
                    
                    attachmentEntity.components.set(BillboardComponent())
                    entity.addChild(attachmentEntity)
                    attachmentEntity.setPosition([0, 0.3, 0], relativeTo: entity)
                }
            } attachments: {
                ForEach(attachmentsProvider.sortedTagViewPairs, id: \.tag) { pair in
                    Attachment(id: pair.tag) {
                        pair.view
                    }
                }
                
                Attachment(id: "movement_controls") {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 60))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .hoverEffect()
                        .pressAction(
                            onPress: {
                                print("⬆️ Up pressed")
                                movementModel.isMovingUp = true
                            },
                            onRelease: {
                                print("⬆️ Up released")
                                movementModel.isMovingUp = false
                            }
                        )
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 100) {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 60))
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .hoverEffect()
                            .pressAction(
                                onPress: {
                                    print("⬅️ Left pressed")
                                    movementModel.isMovingLeft = true
                                },
                                onRelease: {
                                    print("⬅️ Left released")
                                    movementModel.isMovingLeft = false
                                }
                            )
                            
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 60))
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .hoverEffect()
                            .pressAction(
                                onPress: {
                                    print("➡️ Right pressed")
                                    movementModel.isMovingRight = true
                                },
                                onRelease: {
                                    print("➡️ Right released")
                                    movementModel.isMovingRight = false
                                }
                            )
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 60))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .hoverEffect()
                        .pressAction(
                            onPress: {
                                print("⬇️ Down pressed")
                                movementModel.isMovingDown = true
                            },
                            onRelease: {
                                print("⬇️ Down released")
                                movementModel.isMovingDown = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    .padding(30)
                    .background(.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                }
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        isManipulating = true
                        
                        let verticalDelta = Float(value.translation.height) * -0.001
                        let newOffset = movementModel.verticalOffset + verticalDelta
                        if newOffset >= movementModel.ascendLimit {
                            movementModel.verticalOffset = movementModel.ascendLimit
                        } else if newOffset <= -movementModel.descendLimit {
                            movementModel.verticalOffset = -movementModel.descendLimit
                        } else {
                            movementModel.verticalOffset = newOffset
                        }
                        
                        let horizontalDelta = Float(value.translation.width) * 0.001
                        let newHorizontalOffset = movementModel.horizontalOffset + horizontalDelta
                        if abs(newHorizontalOffset) <= movementModel.horizontalLimit {
                            movementModel.horizontalOffset = newHorizontalOffset
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        isManipulating = false
                    }
            )
            .allowsHitTesting(isManipulating)
            .onChange(of: movementModel.verticalOffset) { _, _ in
                if let entity = targetEntity {
                    updateEntityPosition(entity)
                }
            }
            .task {
                appModel.configureGroupSession()
            }
            .task {
                if let currentScene = appModel.currentScene {
                    appModel.registerGroupActivity(for: currentScene)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .open
            }
            .onDisappear {
                positionUpdateTask?.cancel()
                positionUpdateTask = nil
                appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .closed
            }
        }
    }
}


Anchor it to the user
